# PHP - getting content of the POST request

Tags: php, http, post, request

I have problem with getting the content. I don't know the names of the post variables so I can't do this using

```
$variable = $_POST['name'];
```

because I don't know the "name". I want to catch all of the variables sent by POST method.
How can I get keys of the `$_POST[]` array and the corresponding values?

Comment: It's `$_POST` (all caps) and not `$_Post`.

Comment: I vouch for Matthew's comment, but to answer your question; $_POST is an array, and if you *just* want the keys, use the function array_keys($array); which returns an array of keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard for-each:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  // ... Do what you want with $key and $value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

$_POST is just a big array:

```
while(list($keys,$vars) = each($_POST)){ // do something. }
```

Answer (score 1):

for some quick debugging, you can also use

```
print_r ($_POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for each loop

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
   echo "$key = $value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the keys:

```
array_keys($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides `print_r($_POST);` you could also use `var_dump($_POST);`, but most logical solution as mentioned earlier is `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

basically post request will be mapped to array.
for debuging you can call

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

this code will list all array within post array.